Synthetic or derived fact tables
I have a doubt on how to model a situation where the granularity of what we show in the reports does not derive directly from measurements (i.e. classic "facts"), but rather, is synthetically derived from "pure" facts.
In dimensional modelling documentation, facts and dimensions are intended to be "final products", to be used directly by the BI tools. i.e.: there should not be a "presentation layer" on top of them to summarise, enrich or join facts and dimensions.
But what about this example: one company earns money by conveying sale transactions to one or more e-commerces. A report, to be provided to the finance team of this company, must show which transactions have already been paid by the e-commerces.
There are two sources of data, provided by the e-commerces: one is the list of e-commerce purchases with the calculated commissions. This data feed contains one line per transaction. The other source of information is the list of invoices, where each row is an invoice line item, and each line item is the sum of amounts of commissions of the same type in a certain period of time.
From dimensional modelling point of view, I see two fact tables: transactions and invoice_line_items. The desired outcome though is a calculation which requires more than just a join between the two tables. In fact, nuances in the e-commerces' reporting systems determine the need to use "hacks" to reconcile the two sources of information.
Kimball manual does not seem to cover this kind of scenario. Is there something like "derived fact table" in the literature of this discipline? How to call tables that are build from other fact tables in a procedural manner?
